# Facebook regex allow . and ?fref=ufi

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, facebook

I have been using the following regex, to check if it is a valid facebook url: `/^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?$/`

The problem is that, this regex is old, and now some facebook url's has a `.` and `?fref=ufi` in there url example: `https://www.facebook.com/user.moreusername?fref=ufi`How can i fix so that this regex accept that kind of url?

I have been trying to add `\/?(?:?fref=ufi.)?\/` Without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only going off of what you have provided, I have found this to work:

```
^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-\.]*)?(?:\?fref=ufi)?$
```

The difference is in:

```
([\w\-\.]*)? // added the \. for matching the . literally
(?:\?fref=ufi)?$ // this was appended to the end
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jH2nF3/1)

This may not work for all scenarios as I only have your test case to work off of.

Comment: It is working here now, i saw that i have written an extra \ in my regex :) But your is working Thanks alot! :)

Comment: you're welcome! If there other examples that this solution does not satisfy, send me a message I'll update this solution.

Comment: Actually has :) Why doesen't this work? /^[a-zA-Z0-9{0,2}_.-]*$/ It should check if contains more than 2 caracters, annd then if it has a-zA-Z0-9?

Comment: If you're okay with the `_` included, you can do `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. To check if it contains more than 2 characters, you can specify it as `{2,}` which means 2 or more. Without a string to work with this is all I can say.

Comment: Wait what xD What should it look like then?

Comment: Going to go off your statement directly here, is this what you want? `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}).*` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gQ9qM1/1)